# need to send SMS and EMail to group of user if record's status is not changed aftewr 24 hrs?

Tags: php, mysql, email, sms

I am using php and Mysql.
I have a record in my database and i want to check status value of the record after 24hrs of its insertion if it is still in pending or no changed  i want to send an SMS and an Email to some person relevant to the status.
To achieve this i have implemented a solution in which i used a php code but it need to continuously execute and check status of record that may cause DoS.
In Another solution i create a trigger but i can't able to send db values as parameter to the php file. 
so what should be its solution????

Comment: Cronjob is the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways came into my mind for this.

**First**, (*the good way*) using cronjob. It's a really good way.

**Second**, (bad way for your purpose) Check to see which rows has age of 30 days in each request coming to website. There are cons for this way as the website doesn't get visitors for some days then SMS or Emails won't be sent on time. Another bad thing is it executes on every request so loading time and memory will be consumed during this process.

Comment: i need to get some database record values and then forword it to mail and sms. is this possible via cron job??

Comment: try to learn how to use cronjobs. it's possible to execute scripts regularly.

Answer (score 0):

created a php file which contains a functionality of send sms and email.
then create cronjob:

wget http://example.com/x.php

provide full address of your file.

while creating cronjob set time interval 24hrs